# MySQL: How to copy row from one table to another with skipping empty rows in source table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

Can anyone help me turn this PHP/MySQLesque pseudo-code into a working MySQL-query? Tables A and B have identical columns / column order.

```
UPDATE B SET 
B.col_1 = A.col_1 IF(A.col_1 != '' AND A.col_1 != 0 AND A.col_1 != NULL), 
B.col_2 = A.col_2 IF(A.col_2 != '' AND A.col_2 != 0 AND A.col_2 != NULL),
…
B.col_n = A.col_n IF(A.col_n != '' AND A.col_n != 0 AND A.col_n != NULL)
WHERE A.$uniqueField = B.$uniqueField
```

Any of the n columns (email, firstName, lastName, phone, …) can be $uniqueField (handled by PHP), so I can't use insert-on-duplicate-key.

I found many examples to do it the other way round (i.e. copy rows and skip empty fields in target table), including a promising way via COALESCE, but I could not get this to work.

Any help would be highly appreciated ... thanks in advance!

Comment: Exact copy of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60262777/mysql-copy-table-row-and-skip-empty-fields-in-source-table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: Copy table row and skip empty fields in source table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60262777/mysql-copy-table-row-and-skip-empty-fields-in-source-table)

Comment: @forpas you are right, that's a copy of my question from some 8 hours ago. Though I tried to explain my problem, that post was closed ... unfortunately without a solution for my problem. So I edited that post and - since the other one is not accepting answers any more - opened this one, hoping I managed to explain my problem better this time ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, the syntax of your update statement is not correct. In MySQL, you need something like `UPDATE B JOIN A ON ... SET ...`.

When it comes to the logic that you want to implement, although quite unclear, I suspect that this can be managed with `CASE` expressions:

```
UPDATE B 
JOIN A ON A.$uniqueField = B.$uniqueField
SET 
    B.col_1 = CASE 
        WHEN A.col_1 <> '' AND A.col_1 <> '0' 
        THEN A.col_1 
        ELSE B.col_1 
    END,
    B.col_2 = CASE 
        WHEN A.col_2 <> '' AND A.col_2 <> '0'
        THEN A.col_2
        ELSE B.col_2 
    END,
    ...
    B.col_N = CASE 
        WHEN A.col_N <> '' AND A.col_N <> '0'
        THEN A.col_N
        ELSE B.col_N 
    END
```

For each column in the `SET` clause, the query updates it to the corresponding value in `A` (if such a record exists), if the value in `A` is not empty, not `null` and not `0`. I assumed that all columns are of string datatype (hence `'0'` instead of `0` in your pseudo-code), since you do check that values are not empty strings.

Note: as commnented by spencer7503, the nulllity check is redondant: values that satisfy any of the two inequality conditions are guaranteed to be not null.

Comment: thanks! I know it's not correct, it's not MySQL at all, it's just some pseudo-code to show what I need. I will try your code, looks like it's exactly what I need :)

Comment: +10 note the checks of `A.col_X IS NOT NULL` are redundant. Any value that satisfies `<> ''` or `<> '0'` check will already be non-NULL.  (An inequality comparison with a NULL value will always return NULL.)  We might more concisely write  `WHEN A.col_1 NOT IN ('','0') THEN`  (which will evaluate to TRUE for non-NULL values of col_1 that are not equal to empty string and not equal to string '0'

Comment: @spencer7593: ah yes, that's a good point, of course. I modified my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: aside from note about more concise expression of the conditional checks, this is the pattern I would use to conditionally assign a value ... the trick is that ELSE assignment of the current value of the column back to the column itself ... +10

Comment: Copied, studied, understood - works like charm! Thank you everybody! Got my query working and learned something new - you guys made my day! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  B,A

SET B.Col1 = SELECT COALESCE(A.Col1,B.Col1),
    B.Col2  =SELECT COALESCE(A.Col2,B.Col2),
    ...
    B.Coln = SELECT COALESCE(A.Coln.B.Coln)
WHERE A.uniquefield = B.uniquefield  AND Condition
```

Comment: is there a reason we would opt for the old school comma operator for the join operation rather than the newer JOIN keyword?

Comment: That's the way I tried to go some hours ago. I always got (and get) a syntax error, and I couldn't find out why. :(

Thank you though, I really appreciate your help! And some day I will find out where that syntax error comes from ... :)

Comment: Equivalently, you can use                                                 UPDATE  B INNER JOIN A ON A.uniquefield = B.uniquefield

SET B.Col1 = SELECT COALESCE(A.Col1,B.Col1),
    B.Col2  =SELECT COALESCE(A.Col2,B.Col2),
    ...
    B.Coln = SELECT COALESCE(A.Coln.B.Coln)
WHERE Condition

Comment: the query updates B.col  value with A.col value if A.col is not null.